# cat last 5 files in a dir

Tags: bash, cat

I have a directory with filenames of the format $date.txt. I would like to cat 5 latest files from it. Is there a more elegant solution to that, than

```
for f in 2*.txt; do echo $f; done | tail -5 | while read f; do cat $f; done
```

Comment: What is `$date`? Is it something like `Wed May 30 23:28:06 BST 2018`? Or `2018-05-30`? Something else? Does it have spaces? How can `$date.txt` match more than one file?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but the specific format of the date is also relevant. Especially if it can have spaces. Please give us a few examples. Numerical sorting won't always be the same as sorting by date, depending on the format used.

Comment: I also don't understand why it's put on hold as unclear. I've specified the behavior, and got several good solutions, so apparently people understand the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`:

```
files=( 2*.txt )
cat "${files[@]: -5}"
```

This would create an array of the filenames matching the pattern `2*.txt`.  It would then output the contents of the last five of these.

In `zsh`, you can also specify a range of files as part of its *glob qualifiers*:

```
cat 2*.txt([-5,-1])
```

In any POSIX shell, this may also be done through

```
set -- 2*.txt
while [ "$#" -gt 5 ]; do shift; done   # or: [ "$#" -gt 5 ] && shift "$(( $# - 5 ))"
cat "$@"
```

This sets the positional parameters to the filenames matching the pattern.  It then shifts off the names from the beginning of the list until the list only has five elements in it.  `cat` is then invoked on the remaining filenames.

In all of these solutions, the files would be sorted lexicographically.  Filenames with spaces or newlines are handled correctly.

Comment: `shift $(($# - 5))` might also work to shift to the last 5  - it may complain if fewer than 5 files were found.

Comment: @muru Yes, something like `[ "$#" -gt 5 ] && shift "$(( "$#" - 5 ))"` maybe.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, and I also like the expressive syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a while read loop, this would handle files with spaces.

```
ls 2*.txt | tail -5 | while read loop
do
  cat "$loop" 
done
```

If you always want the 5 most recent you could change it to `ls -tr | tail -5`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question, with no prospect of spaces and 2*.txt happily returning correct ordering, how about

```
cat $(ls 2*.txt|tail -5)
```

Comment: Unless the filenames are MMDDYYYY, or worse, `YYYY MM DD`, with spaces.

Comment: @Jeff, sure, now qualified

Comment: Given that `ls` doesn't really do anything here, I'd usually recommend something else in it's place. But `printf "%s\n" 2*.txt` is a bit hairy to write. Just make sure you don't have `ls` aliased to anything funny if you do this in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `latest` in question, we can check with the modification time of files in the directory.

```
 cat $(ls -ltr *.txt | tail -n5 | awk '{print $NF}' | tr '\n' ' ')
```

- `ls -ltr` - will list files with respect to modification timestamp (reverse)
- `tail -n5` - will take last 5 files
- `$NF` - last field
- `tr` - transpose column to row

Comment: Why the -l, seems unnecessary

Comment: You can lose the `-l` from `ls`, the `awk` along with it, and the `tr` is unnecessary too. So `cat $(ls -tr *.txt | tail -n5)` should do, with all the usual problems with whitespace and glob characters in file names.

Comment: @illkkachu You are right, but that will list files in ascending order rather than lastest.